# Why is the process state in task_struct stored as type 'long'?

Tags: linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel tree, the file `/include/linux/sched.h` contains `task_struct` which, among other data, defines a variable `volatile long state`.

According to [this page](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ygz/378-02S/lecture09.html), the number stored in `state` represents one of five states:

```
#define TASK_RUNNING            0
#define TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE      1
#define TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE    2
#define TASK_ZOMBIE             4
#define TASK_STOPPED            8
```

My question is as follows:

**Why is such a large datatype used to store the state**?  Wouldn't a single byte be perfectly sufficient to store the states above? Surely, `long` wasn't chosen in anticipation of thousands/millions of possible states?

I'm aware that the definition of `long` will vary across the different architectures, but I thought `char` would have sufficed.

Comment: Did you examine actual content of that header? There is `#define TASK_NOLOAD 1024` definition, so task state definitely cannot fit into `char`. Probably, another flags will be added in the future, that is even `int` will be not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily see these values are power-of-2. This is the standard way to handle /flags/. You can logically OR ('|') them to create cobined states. And then you can easily test them with AND ('&').

long on a 32-bit platform will only be 32-bit.

So, with long on a 32-bit platform you only have 32 distinct flags, as opposed to millions.

Finally, I strongly suggest inspecting actual sources and preferably from this decade, see:

```
#define TASK_RUNNING            0
#define TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE      1
#define TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE    2
#define __TASK_STOPPED          4
#define __TASK_TRACED           8
/* in tsk->exit_state */
#define EXIT_DEAD               16
#define EXIT_ZOMBIE             32
#define EXIT_TRACE              (EXIT_ZOMBIE | EXIT_DEAD)
/* in tsk->state again */
#define TASK_DEAD               64
#define TASK_WAKEKILL           128
#define TASK_WAKING             256
#define TASK_PARKED             512
#define TASK_NOLOAD             1024
#define TASK_STATE_MAX          2048
```

And flag usage below, e.g.

```
#define TASK_KILLABLE           (TASK_WAKEKILL | TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE)
```

So, the question is why would this be long instead of an int. That I don't know, but it is unlikely there is any particularly good reason.

Comment: long could also have to deal with register size...8 bytes makes sense for 64 bit processors